# Can I use two remote-controlled LEGO Tracked Racers 42065 simultaneously?

Tags: power-functions, remote-control

I want to buy two sets of the [LEGO Tracked Racer 42065](https://shop.lego.com/en-US/RC-Tracked-Racer-42065?p=42065) so that my children can play together. I can't tell if they would be able to use the racers simultaneously.

Are the IR receivers multi-channel? Can the sets be raced simultaneously?

Comment: Great question and welcome to Bricks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, LEGO's Power Function IR elements have 4 different channels you can switch between with an orange slider on the receivers and remotes, so you can run up to 4 at a time.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Another friend in our LUG uses 4 models at a time. Two for each of her sons, one for their uncle and one for herself...

She redid the models in splendid new color schemes:
[image: top]
[image]

Comment: That's very cool with the customizations. What is LUG?

Comment: Lego user group... a lego club operating in a certain way... some are recognized by the LEGO group, those are RLUGs, they can offer advantages to their members with support from LEGO but also have some responsibilities towards LEGO then. I'm sure you can find a LUG in your area if you are so inclined...

Comment: Thank you. I didn’t know. I live in São Paulo, Brazil. I imagine a city this size has to have a LUG or RLUG. I’ll do some research. Thank you for the insight.

Comment: The following website can be used to locate a LUG: https://lan.lego.com/clubs/overview/ So for you that would be LUG Brazil, I met some quite nice people of that LUG at the Portugal fanweekend event last weekend ;)